# But how does JavaScript mange prototype property?

Tags: javascript

let us create an empty object {} this object does have a constructor object representing the function responsible for creating the empty object and the constructor object does have a prototype object which is responsible for setting the proto for the to be created object this prototype object itself has a constructor property and so on you can go with this as far as you can (constructor > prototype > constructor > prototype > constructor > prototype > …)

the question is how does JavaScript mange all this Infinitely nested objects ?

Comment: The recursion stops at the `Object` prototype.

Comment: That chain will keep cycling through one single constructor and prototype, not the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

The `constructor` property of a `constructor.prototype` object is not the `constructor` of the prototype object but the `constructor` itself.

If I have a class, say `A`:

```
class A { }
```

And then you create an instance of `A`:

```
let a = new A();
```

The `constructor` property of `a` will be `A`. That is to say, `A` built `a`.

```
a.constructor === A
```

Which also means that:

```
a.constructor.prototype = A.prototype
//          A.prototype = A.prototype
//          since A === a.constructor
```

Now, the constructor of `A.prototype` is not `A.prototype.constructor` that would be `Object` (or rather it could be, you don't need a constructor to create an object really). Because the prototype of `A.prototype` is actually `Object.prototype` and the prototype of `Object.prototype` is null.

The `prototype` property of any `constructor` will be the prototype of their constructed objects and it's NOT the prototype of the object it belongs to.

If you keep doing:

`a.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor...` you will be doing circles around the constructor prototype and the constructor itself because:

```
A.prototype.constructor = A
```

Comment: But how does it do that.. I mean assign its prototype.constructor to itself?

Comment: @KhalidAlluhybi yes, that's right. You can do `let A = { cyclic: { } }; A.cyclic.prop = A`. Which would let you do `A.cyclic.prop.cyclic.prop.cyclic...`

Comment: But really, a loop here is not the intention. It just so happens that the `constructor` includes the `prototype`. The real usefulness of this is that you can access the `constructor` which built (or can build) a particular instance of an object. That is to say, you could know that `{ }` was built (or can be built) with `Object` since `{ }.constructor` is that.